# DS87C520: Dispose or sell?

Tags: microcontroller, identification, microchip

My company just got rid of a branch and there's a bit of hardware that I could (legally) save before going into the trashcans. I have no idea wether these chips are just old garbage or precious oldies that are rare nowadays. There are 44 items of this kind, does anybody know them and if they are worth being put on ebay? I don't mean to make a lot of money out of them, but sometimes people are still looking for older spare parts. Thanks for your comments. Here's a close-up:

[image]

Comment: u mean these https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/maxim-integrated/DS87C520-QCL-/DS87C520-QCL--ND/957014

Comment: Yeah, those are expensive. I'm not sure why they're that expensive for being micro-controllers.

Comment: Old OTP stuff (one-time programmable). You should probably be sure they are blank before you sell them.

Comment: I think this might be a different model, but I honestly have no clue as this is not my field... but you're right, of course, the price is surprisingly high! ô¿ô Maybe someone can shed some more light on the details? That's getting exciting! ;)

Comment: When you went on eBay and searched for ds87c520, what did you find?

Comment: This part is a fossil, but some people may still have hardware that needs this, hence the ludicrous price on digikey. It seems to use EEPROM instead of Flash... Sell the lot to an obsolete parts reseller like Rochester, you'll make some people happy...

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I didn't do that yet, I didn't imagine that they are of any use now. Apparently, some people may still need them, so I'm glad I saved them. Thank you, Tut, for pointing that out! They are all packed in some kind of transparent bar, so I don't think they ever got touched, but I'll better find out if they are.

Comment: @Robert - I was trying to point out (gently) that you failed to do the most minimal amount of obvious research before you asked your question. The simplest way to tell what a part is going for on eBay is to go on eBay and search for examples of the part. Next time, do your homework first. We're glad to help with questions which need our expertise, but this wasn't one of them.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Nevermind, my main reason for asking here was curiosity and getting to know *what* these thingies are, for some hard-to-explain nostalgic reasons.

Comment: Sell it or give it away, some people still need these old obsolete parts. Do them a service. If you want to profit from it, it's up to you.

Comment: @Tut it says fully pin compatible with an 8051 in the datasheet. Anything truly drop-in pin compatible with an 8051 can be externally forced into an 8031 mode no matter what is or isn't in the ROM.

Answer (score 1):

These have value to 8051 enthusiasts - though their usability is somewhat limited by the OTP EPROM design. These can be used to either build something that you already have working and debugged code for - or to build 8031/8032 style systems with an external code memory.